# Flutter double nested json list to Dart model

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to convert this json response to a dart model, but I can't figure out how to parse "standings" which is a double nested list. What im trying at the moment doesnt work (i thought i should access the first element in the higher list):

```
 StandingLeague.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    country = json['country'];
    logo = json['logo'];
    flag = json['flag'];
    season = json['season'];
    if (json['standings'] != null) {
      standings = <Standing>[];
      json['standings'][0].forEach((v) { standings?.add(v); });
    }
  }
```

Json response:

```
{
        "league": {
            "id": 39,
            "name": "Premier League",
            "country": "England",
            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/39.png",
            "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg",
            "season": 2022,
            "standings": [
                [
                    {
                        "rank": 1,
                        "team": {
                            "id": 42,
                            "name": "Arsenal",
                            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/42.png"
                        },
                        "points": 18,
                        "goalsDiff": 10,
                        "group": "Premier League",
                        "form": "WLWWW",
                        "status": "same",
                        "description": "Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)",
                        "all": {
                            "played": 7,
                            "win": 6,
                            "draw": 0,
                            "lose": 1,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 17,
                                "against": 7
                            }
                        },
                        "home": {
                            "played": 3,
                            "win": 3,
                            "draw": 0,
                            "lose": 0,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 8,
                                "against": 4
                            }
                        },
                        "away": {
                            "played": 4,
                            "win": 3,
                            "draw": 0,
                            "lose": 1,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 9,
                                "against": 3
                            }
                        },
                        "update": "2022-09-18T00:00:00+00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "rank": 2,
                        "team": {
                            "id": 50,
                            "name": "Manchester City",
                            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/50.png"
                        },
                        "points": 17,
                        "goalsDiff": 17,
                        "group": "Premier League",
                        "form": "WDWWD",
                        "status": "same",
                        "description": "Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)",
                        "all": {
                            "played": 7,
                            "win": 5,
                            "draw": 2,
                            "lose": 0,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 23,
                                "against": 6
                            }
                        },
                        "home": {
                            "played": 3,
                            "win": 3,
                            "draw": 0,
                            "lose": 0,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 14,
                                "against": 2
                            }
                        },
                        "away": {
                            "played": 4,
                            "win": 2,
                            "draw": 2,
                            "lose": 0,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 9,
                                "against": 4
                            }
                        },
                        "update": "2022-09-18T00:00:00+00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "rank": 3,
                        "team": {
                            "id": 47,
                            "name": "Tottenham",
                            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/47.png"
                        },
                        "points": 17,
                        "goalsDiff": 11,
                        "group": "Premier League",
                        "form": "WWDWW",
                        "status": "same",
                        "description": "Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)",
                        "all": {
                            "played": 7,
                            "win": 5,
                            "draw": 2,
                            "lose": 0,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 18,
                                "against": 7
                            }
                        },
                        "home": {
                            "played": 4,
                            "win": 4,
                            "draw": 0,
                            "lose": 0,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 13,
                                "against": 4
                            }
                        },
                        "away": {
                            "played": 3,
                            "win": 1,
                            "draw": 2,
                            "lose": 0,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 5,
                                "against": 3
                            }
                        },
                        "update": "2022-09-18T00:00:00+00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "rank": 4,
                        "team": {
                            "id": 51,
                            "name": "Brighton",
                            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/51.png"
                        },
                        "points": 13,
                        "goalsDiff": 6,
                        "group": "Premier League",
                        "form": "WLWWD",
                        "status": "same",
                        "description": "Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)",
                        "all": {
                            "played": 6,
                            "win": 4,
                            "draw": 1,
                            "lose": 1,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 11,
                                "against": 5
                            }
                        },
                        "home": {
                            "played": 3,
                            "win": 2,
                            "draw": 1,
                            "lose": 0,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 6,
                                "against": 2
                            }
                        },
                        "away": {
                            "played": 3,
                            "win": 2,
                            "draw": 0,
                            "lose": 1,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 5,
                                "against": 3
                            }
                        },
                        "update": "2022-09-18T00:00:00+00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "rank": 5,
                        "team": {
                            "id": 33,
                            "name": "Manchester United",
                            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/33.png"
                        },
                        "points": 12,
                        "goalsDiff": 0,
                        "group": "Premier League",
                        "form": "WWWWL",
                        "status": "same",
                        "description": "Promotion - Europa League (Group Stage)",
                        "all": {
                            "played": 6,
                            "win": 4,
                            "draw": 0,
                            "lose": 2,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 8,
                                "against": 8
                            }
                        },
                        "home": {
                            "played": 3,
                            "win": 2,
                            "draw": 0,
                            "lose": 1,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 6,
                                "against": 4
                            }
                        },
                        "away": {
                            "played": 3,
                            "win": 2,
                            "draw": 0,
                            "lose": 1,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 2,
                                "against": 4
                            }
                        },
                        "update": "2022-09-18T00:00:00+00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "rank": 6,
                        "team": {
                            "id": 36,
                            "name": "Fulham",
                            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/36.png"
                        },
                        "points": 11,
                        "goalsDiff": 1,
                        "group": "Premier League",
                        "form": "WLWLW",
                        "status": "same",
                        "description": null,
                        "all": {
                            "played": 7,
                            "win": 3,
                            "draw": 2,
                            "lose": 2,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 12,
                                "against": 11
                            }
                        },
                        "home": {
                            "played": 3,
                            "win": 2,
                            "draw": 1,
                            "lose": 0,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 7,
                                "against": 5
                            }
                        },
                        "away": {
                            "played": 4,
                            "win": 1,
                            "draw": 1,
                            "lose": 2,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 5,
                                "against": 6
                            }
                        },
                        "update": "2022-09-18T00:00:00+00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "rank": 7,
                        "team": {
                            "id": 49,
                            "name": "Chelsea",
                            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/49.png"
                        },
                        "points": 10,
                        "goalsDiff": -1,
                        "group": "Premier League",
                        "form": "WLWLD",
                        "status": "same",
                        "description": null,
                        "all": {
                            "played": 6,
                            "win": 3,
                            "draw": 1,
                            "lose": 2,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 8,
                                "against": 9
                            }
                        },
                        "home": {
                            "played": 3,
                            "win": 2,
                            "draw": 1,
                            "lose": 0,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 6,
                                "against": 4
                            }
                        },
                        "away": {
                            "played": 3,
                            "win": 1,
                            "draw": 0,
                            "lose": 2,
                            "goals": {
                                "for": 2,
                                "against": 5
                            }
                        },
                        "update": "2022-09-18T00:00:00+00:00"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give instance of your `json` to https://app.quicktype.io/ to get model based on, here is example of your json model:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final standingLeague = standingLeagueFromMap(jsonString);

import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

StandingLeague standingLeagueFromMap(String str) => StandingLeague.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String standingLeagueToMap(StandingLeague data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class StandingLeague {
    StandingLeague({
        @required this.league,
    });

    League league;

    factory StandingLeague.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => StandingLeague(
        league: League.fromMap(json["league"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "league": league.toMap(),
    };
}

class League {
    League({
        @required this.id,
        @required this.name,
        @required this.country,
        @required this.logo,
        @required this.flag,
        @required this.season,
        @required this.standings,
    });

    int id;
    String name;
    String country;
    String logo;
    String flag;
    int season;
    List<List<Standing>> standings;

    factory League.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => League(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        country: json["country"],
        logo: json["logo"],
        flag: json["flag"],
        season: json["season"],
        standings: List<List<Standing>>.from(json["standings"].map((x) => List<Standing>.from(x.map((x) => Standing.fromMap(x))))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "country": country,
        "logo": logo,
        "flag": flag,
        "season": season,
        "standings": List<dynamic>.from(standings.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(x.map((x) => x.toMap())))),
    };
}

class Standing {
    Standing({
        @required this.rank,
        @required this.team,
        @required this.points,
        @required this.goalsDiff,
        @required this.group,
        @required this.form,
        @required this.status,
        @required this.description,
        @required this.all,
        @required this.home,
        @required this.away,
        @required this.update,
    });

    int rank;
    Team team;
    int points;
    int goalsDiff;
    String group;
    String form;
    String status;
    String description;
    All all;
    All home;
    All away;
    DateTime update;

    factory Standing.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Standing(
        rank: json["rank"],
        team: Team.fromMap(json["team"]),
        points: json["points"],
        goalsDiff: json["goalsDiff"],
        group: json["group"],
        form: json["form"],
        status: json["status"],
        description: json["description"] == null ? null : json["description"],
        all: All.fromMap(json["all"]),
        home: All.fromMap(json["home"]),
        away: All.fromMap(json["away"]),
        update: DateTime.parse(json["update"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "rank": rank,
        "team": team.toMap(),
        "points": points,
        "goalsDiff": goalsDiff,
        "group": group,
        "form": form,
        "status": status,
        "description": description == null ? null : description,
        "all": all.toMap(),
        "home": home.toMap(),
        "away": away.toMap(),
        "update": update.toIso8601String(),
    };
}

class All {
    All({
        @required this.played,
        @required this.win,
        @required this.draw,
        @required this.lose,
        @required this.goals,
    });

    int played;
    int win;
    int draw;
    int lose;
    Goals goals;

    factory All.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => All(
        played: json["played"],
        win: json["win"],
        draw: json["draw"],
        lose: json["lose"],
        goals: Goals.fromMap(json["goals"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "played": played,
        "win": win,
        "draw": draw,
        "lose": lose,
        "goals": goals.toMap(),
    };
}

class Goals {
    Goals({
        @required this.goalsFor,
        @required this.against,
    });

    int goalsFor;
    int against;

    factory Goals.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Goals(
        goalsFor: json["for"],
        against: json["against"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "for": goalsFor,
        "against": against,
    };
}

class Team {
    Team({
        @required this.id,
        @required this.name,
        @required this.logo,
    });

    int id;
    String name;
    String logo;

    factory Team.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Team(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        logo: json["logo"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "logo": logo,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put all your json in https://app.quicktype.io/ and it will give a model,